# Gmail doesn't show own domain mail

Tags: email, dns, gmail

I have changed my domain provider to Goddady, also I have my own server so I set domain DNS to this server...

Inside cPanel, I changed mail DNS to google DNS, and all the email is received on the mailboxes correctly.

The problem comes when I try to send mails from Wordpress to any mail from the same domain, gmail doesn't show it, but the email are achieving the server.
From webmail I can check this, only the wordpress mails are arriving to the server, but no to gmail mailbox.

If I try to send mail from Wordpress to another mail (not same domain) it works...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Open server ports 465 and 587 and set gmail smtp in Wordpress